# How can I create a network proxy programming?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, proxy

### Excuse me. I speak poor English.

I am trying to create a network proxy programming with sock5 protocol. But I have no way to learn it, I can't figure out how a proxy programming works especially the followings:

1. What is the difference and association between socks5 and the Shadowsocks ?
2. Can I set a the network proxy configure in macOs instead of using swift or oc ?

such as enabling this check button(socks5 proxy) and filling the specific configure using a language instead of swift or oc:
[configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNAxc.jpg)

3. Once I set the option on macOs in the Question 2,what kind of data will the programming get if it listening the network?

e.g. will the macOs automatically forward the all new TCP connections to 127.0.0.1:1086 and automatically make the connections confirm to the socks5 request standard?

If so, why the final processing programming (transmit the datas to the real remote proxy-server) can make a successful connection? Instead of a forever loop(a.programming create a socket to remote proxy-server -> b. macOs automatically forward it to 127.0.0.1:1086 and make the connection confirm to the socks5 request standard -> a.)

4. Is it called as a proxy-client? or local proxy-server? what is the job of it. Why do I set a proxy address as a local one instead of a direct remote server?
5. Why when I setting a fake socks5 option in macOs network proxy options, a UDP programming can still work successfully?

### If you can UNDERSTAND CHINESE:

[Chinese language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0HMw.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

The follow answers are based on my own experience and opinion.

1、**`socks5`** is an `Internet protocol` that exchanges network packets between a client and server through a proxy server. [`Sockes`](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/SOCKS) 
while **`Shadowsocks`** is a software use this protocol.

2 、Yes,you can. Install a **`Shaowsocks`** don't need any 
Programming language, actually it like installing a `EXE` file on `Windows` or pkg on `MacOS`, it's just a software.

3、**`Socks5`** is an `Internet protocol` like a language between two computer.
The software's message  run on you computer will be "translated" by **`Shadowsocks`**.
Those translated message will be sent to the remote service (also run a **`Shadowsocks`**) then the service can send message to those `"blocked"` Webs' services.

4、The remote service can be called an **`proxy service`**.The local don't do anything except be "translated" by **`Shadowsocks`**. Look [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf83h.png).

5、The `QQ` don't use the `port` 1080, **`Shadowsocks`** need a `fixed port` to "translate" message.